# How to find the sum of series?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

input @n int  = 5

It should generate series as 1,2,3,4,5

Expected result: Should show sum 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

Sum = 15

How could i do this using SQL Server

Comment: If you just want sum then use the formula `n*(n + 1) / 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @n INT = 5;

WITH num(i) AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i+1 AS i FROM num WHERE i <= @n - 1
)
SELECT SUM(i) FROM num
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @n int = 5;
declare @sum int;

set @sum = @n * (@n + 1) / 2;
select @sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @n int = 5
Declare @o int=0
while @n>=1
begin
 set @o=@o+@n
 set @n=@n-1
End

select @o
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
   declare @n int 
   set @n= 5;
   declare @sum int;

   set @sum = @n * (@n + 1) / 2;
   select @sum
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
declare @n int
set @n=5
declare @sum1 int
set @sum1=0
declare @i int
set @i=0
print 'the Series is'
while @i<@n
begin
print @i+1
set @i=@i+1
set @sum1=@sum1+@i
end
print 'the sum is'
print  @sum1
```